# Stop Eclipse to show documents when mouse is hover over words in double quotation

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse IDE to write my JAVA program. I know that one the very helpful things about IDEs is that they show documents when you hover your mouse over things like functions, variables etc. But recently I noticed that when my cursor is hover over some words in double quotation the document window pops up which is very ignoring me, how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Will that work for you? http://www.eclipseonetips.com/2010/08/24/configure-tooltips-in-eclipse-to-only-popup-on-request/

Comment: @mazaneicha that was exactly what I needed, thanks indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to here   `Window - Preferences; select Java -> Editor -> Hovers` and check what option you selected and change it. I am using Eclipse Kepler With these settings its working fine someone how you made some changes in configuration

[image]

Comment: Note that if you disable `Combined Hover` this will disables all hovers for wich a key Modifier is defined, you will have to press the key conbination and hover in order to see the tooltip. Also note that this makes no difference whether the hovered text is in a string literal or a variabel definition.